# Compound mysql COUNT queries with multiple AND OR conditions

Tags: mysql

The following mysql query is intended to JOIN a multitude of tables together and to do counts on those tables each one according to the time of the given table.

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) AS textcnt,
   COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) AS favcnt
                    FROM stream_updates s 
                        LEFT JOIN favorites f
                    ON f.username=s.username                        
                        INNER JOIN members m
                    ON m.username=s.username 
                    WHERE (m.username = 'testuser1'
                    AND (m.username IN (
                           SELECT friend2 as username FROM list_friends 
                           WHERE (friend1 = 'testuser1' AND friend2 <> 'testuser1') 
                    )) OR (m.username IN (
                           SELECT friend1 as username FROM list_friends
                           WHERE (friend2 = 'testuser1' AND friend1 <> 'testuser1')
                    ))) AND (s.time between (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()
                    OR (f.time between (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()))
```

For some reason the above ALWAYS returns zero.

Here is an example query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a88f1e/1

The query from the example SHOULD return:

```
textcnt: 2 // id's 1 and 4 from the stream_updates table
favcnt: 1 // id 1 from the favorites table
```

Instead it is returning 0 for both counts

Please understand if you are going to suggest a rewrite of the queries that I am actually counting 5 tables with LEFT JOINs, I just stripped it down for simplicity.

I am also having difficulty correctly writing the WHERE clause. It needs to check if user exists in members table, and if so perform query on user. Then it needs to check to see if the user is in the list_friends table, and if so further perform the query on the friends of the user. I am worried the way I have it written it will check to ensure that both are taking place. However if I change it from an AND to an OR, I have the problem where if the user is in the members table, the query will not perform the OR.

**UPDATE TO CLARIFY WHERE CLAUSE**

I am trying to do the following in the where clause:

First get all the counts of the member 'testuser1'

Second, if testuser1 has friends listed in list_friends include their results in the counts as well.

Third, base results of each table off the past 24 hours based on the 'time' it was posted.

ADDITIONAL NOTE, I also have other queries where I grab the past 48 hours subtracting the past 24 hours (thus results from 2 days ago but not today)... and it goes on, so please do not rewrite in such a way it will grab "the past 24 hours" because then I apply elsewhere it will grab "That past 48 hours" not "24 hours from 2 days ago".

Comment: sqlfiddle, plus 1

Comment: You have an impossible where clause that will never ever return any records, hence the 0 returned by the queries. If I simply the where clause, you are looking for a record, where m.username = 'testuser1' and (m.username<>'testuser1 or m.username<>'testuser1). Can you pls describe in plain English what the where criteria should do?

Comment: @Shadow I attempted to do that by adding it to the question.